# How to use ngx-facebook in Angular 4 application with SystemJs module system

Tags: facebook, angular

I have tried out many variations to specifying path in SystemJS to load the ngx-facebook package.

System.config({

```
"defaultJSExtensions": true,
"paths": {
  '@angular/core': 'node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    ...
    "*": "node_modules/*",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap",
    'ngx-facebook':'node_modules/ngx-facebook',
},
"packages": {
   'ngx-facebook': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'dist/umd/index.js'
},
```

}
});

Am getting Facebook Service undefined. Could any one help me.

Comment: Can you post the error and code snippets?